# Where to find all available Java mail properties?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

Where do I find a list of all available Java mail properties that I can pass to the Session object? I am only able to find basic properties in the API. Browsing blogs to find some more properties isn't good. There must be some list somewhere?

Comment: The mail properties are on the mail server.

Comment: have you taken a look to this link by the way? there are a goog quantity of properties: http://connector.sourceforge.net/doc-files/Properties.html

Comment: connector.sourceforge... link is merely a subset of properties, with links to other small subsets.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In the api is a reference to the properties for the specific sun protocol providers. Not sure if you were looking for these:

- https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html
- https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html
- https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html

These are also set on the session object but you use them on your own risk since in other mail implementations they are maybe not supported or they change in the future.

Comment: links are broken

Comment: @vlio20 thx. I have corrected the links to the new github location.