# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate

Tags: java, smtp, gmail-api

I know there is several issue created about this error but nothing was helpful for me. I have method  which is sending email with attachment on gmail server and it works fine. yesterday I bought a new mac mini m1. I tried this method to send email but it's throwing this error

```
 public static void sentEmail(String report){  
    BaseTest base = new BaseTest();
    
      
      String to = base.getProps().getProperty("emailTO"); ;//change accordingly  
      final String user = base.getProps().getProperty("emailFROM");//change accordingly  
      final String password = base.getProps().getProperty("emailPassword");//change accordingly  
       
      //1) get the session object     
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();  
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  
      properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
      properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");  
      properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
      
      
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,  
       new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
       protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
       return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);  
       }  
      });  
         
      //2) compose message     
      try{  
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));  
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
        message.setSubject("From Mobile Automation Project ");  
          
        //3) create MimeBodyPart object and set your message text     
        BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();  
        messageBodyPart1.setText("Report");  
          
        //4) create new MimeBodyPart object and set DataHandler object to this object      
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();  
      
        String filename = report;//change accordingly  
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);  
        messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));  
        messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);  
         
         
        //5) create Multipart object and add MimeBodyPart objects to this object      
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();  
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);  
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);  
      
        //6) set the multiplart object to the message object  
        message.setContent(multipart );  
         
        //7) send message  
        Transport.send(message);  
       
       System.out.println("Report has been sent to: "+ to);  
       }catch (MessagingException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}  
}
```

Exception

```
    javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1907)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:666)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.qa.utils.TestUtils.SendEmailTLS(TestUtils.java:228)
    at com.qa.BaseTest.afterSuite(BaseTest.java:153)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:63)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:348)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:302)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:351)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:428)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:562)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:548)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:171)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:101)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:238)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:394)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:373)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:549)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:486)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1902)
    ... 31 more
```

I changed this parameter

```
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
```

To this

```
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
```

But then I'm getting this exception

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.qa.utils.TestUtils.sentEmail(TestUtils.java:189)
    at com.qa.BaseTest.afterSuite(BaseTest.java:152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:63)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:348)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:302)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:351)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:428)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:562)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:548)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:555)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:321)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: Which client library are you using?

Comment: I'm using javax.mail

Comment: on old mac this code is working, I checked it one more time :/  I think something is blocking smpt protocol on a mac mini

Answer (score 25):

I had a similar issue and it seems to be related to [Deepak's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68238768). Following [these instructions](https://groups.google.com/g/dspace-tech/c/clqlwv3r_zY/m/AGVMg4OPBQAJ) solved the problem.

It seems to be necessary to explicitly set `required` flag and the protocols:

Adding the following settings worked for me:

```java
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```

I have to add that I tested this on port 465 and the full configuration looks like this

```java
properies.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
properies.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
properies.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properies.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properies.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
properies.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
properies.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
```

Comment: thanks' its worked and solved my issue

Comment: Where to put these lines?

Comment: @MohitTomar You can set these properties when initializing the session ([javax.mail.Session.getInstance(Properties))](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Session.html#getInstance-java.util.Properties-). Alternatively, these are read from the system properties. See also this answer for a list of properties: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16595037.

Comment: I use Zoho mail, properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2") is important!

Answer (score 4):

Warning do this own risk of enabling tlsv1 and tlsv1.1:

1. find the directory where java.security file saved.
   in the case of ubuntu:

   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security
2. find `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`
3. remove `TLSv1, TLSv1.1`
4. reboot the server and run the project to try to send mail again.

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded my javax.mail to 1.6.2 and solved the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Upgrading javax.mail.jar to 1.6.2 solved the issue for me, too. Found here: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release

Answer (score 1):

my solution is enable secure port and TLSv1.2 .

```
mail.smtp.port=587
mail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve that issue, just upgrade the java library used to sendmail.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

update mail dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

I faced this issue due to older version of **mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar**
Upgrading to **5.1.49** version solved my issue

Comment: Why mysql? The question is about javax.mail